# How to find object in a List of Items by index using es6 (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react and es6 syntax, suppose I have a list of objects like below (**testData.js**)

```js
export const favourites=[
    {
        name: 'Jhon Doe',
        avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    },
    {
        name: 'Micheal Douglas',
        avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    },
    {
        name: 'Camille la cruz',
        avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    },
    {
        name: 'The Rock',
        avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    },
    {
        name: 'Daniel lacharmante',
        avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    },
    {
        name: 'Alber Weiter',
        avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    }

]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

And let say I've imported it into a file, let say **test.js**, so to use this list I've done

```js
    const favouritePersonList =favouritePersonData.map(person=>{
        return <Avatar key={person} avatarurl={person.avatarUrl} style={styles.favouritePersons} height={40} width={40} activity/>
     })
```

which is suppose to create a List of Avatar component, and put the needed props etc...Now what I would like to do is to render the first object/component in this list. I tried

```js
render(
        <div>
        {favouritePersonList[0]}
        </div>
)
```

But no success, can someone help me ? thanks

As requested please find the full avatar code, kindly note that it is a react native code.

```js
export default class Avatar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            userState : '#1cdb4c'

        }
    }


    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.activity? this.setState({userState:'#1cdb4c'}): this.setState({userState:'#f93434'})
    }

    render() {
        const {height, width, avatarUrl}=this.props
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.avatarContainer,{height:height,width:width}]}>
        <Image style={styles.avatarImg} 
        source={avatarUrl}
        
        />
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.userActivity,{height:height, width:width}]}>
        <View style={styles.outer}>
        <View style={[styles.inner,{backgroundColor:this.state.userState}]}/>
        </View>
        </View>
         </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code works for me. You are passing a wrong key. `person` here is an object. So, pass a property as a unique value. Just for testing, pass the names and check that you can see it. Maybe your styling is wrong, maybe you can't get the images, etc. So, maybe you should give more detail.

Comment: why the export const has name `favourites` but in test.js you use `favouritePersonData`? Have you checked if they are the same?

Comment: Can you show us your whole code? Including the `Avatar` component. As I said your code works for a simple case. I can proivde a working example. Obviosuly your problem is somwhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, your code works for a simple case. Here it is:

```js
const favourites = [
  {
    name: "Jhon Doe",
  },
  {
    name: "Micheal Douglas",
  },
  {
    name: "Camille la cruz",
  },
  {
    name: "The Rock",
  },
  {
    name: "Daniel lacharmante",
  },
  {
    name: "Alber Weiter",
  },
];

const Avatar = props => <div>{props.name}</div>;

const App = () => {
  const favouritePersonList = favourites.map( person => (
    <Avatar key={person.name} name={person.name} />
  ) );
  return <div>{favouritePersonList[ 0 ]}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

So, the problem must be somewhere else. Please share us your whole code with the `Avatar` component.

**Update**

This is a blind suggestion but in your `Avatar` component, you are using `source={avatarUrl}` for the `Image`. Two problems here.

1. You are not using props. (Sorry, I've seen now, you are destructuring it from `this.props`. So, just change the destructuring name.
2. You are using the wrong prop name. It should be `avatarurl` since you are passing it like that in the parent component.

So, try like this:

```
export default class Avatar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            userState : '#1cdb4c'

        }
    }


    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.activity? this.setState({userState:'#1cdb4c'}): this.setState({userState:'#f93434'})
    }

    render() {
        const {height, width, avatarurl}=this.props
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={[styles.avatarContainer,{height:height,width:width}]}>
        <Image style={styles.avatarImg} 
        source={avatarurl}

        />
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.userActivity,{height:height, width:width}]}>
        <View style={styles.outer}>
        <View style={[styles.inner,{backgroundColor:this.state.userState}]}/>
        </View>
        </View>
         </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I think you are right lol. Please find the full code of the avatar compo  above :)

Comment: omg I feel so guilty now, thank you so much for your help and your time

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want your component to display, but you might use something roughly like this:

```
render(
  <div>
     {favoritePersonList.map(person => {
       return (
         <div>
           <h1>{person.name}</h1>
           <img src={person.avatarUrl} alt={person.name}/>
         </div>
       )
     })}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use this `favouritePersonList` instead of this `favouritePersonList[0]` because you want to render a whole list not just a single element of it so your code will be

```
render() {
    return  (
      <div>
        {favouritePersonList}
      </div>
    )
}
```

**Edit:**

I didn't notice you wanted to render the first element only

The easiest way will be not to use map in the first place

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {<Avatar avatarurl={favouritePersonData[0].avatarUrl} style={styles.favouritePersons} height={40} width={40} activity/>}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `favouritePersonList[0]` should work. This can't be the problem.

Comment: I think he is trying to only render the something to represent the first object in that array

Comment: erm thats what I want xD I want to render only the first component in the list.. in this case the first avatar :)

Comment: oh, I didn't notice!
I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like you're just calling JavaScript functions. A for loop would work for you like below:

```
let avatarRows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < favourites.length; i++) {
    // note: we add a key prop here to allow react to uniquely identify each
    // element in this array. see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
    avatarRows.push(<Avatar key={favourites[i]} avatarurl={favourites[i].avatarUrl} style={styles.favouritePersons} height={40} width={40} activity/>);
}
return <div>{avatarRows}</div>;
```

Or

```
return <div>{avatarRows[0]}</div>;
```

for the first Avatar component.

Comment: Hello, that's an interesting piece of code and explanation. But the problem i'm having is that I want to display the first avatar in the array :) not all the components. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you please let me know if it works for you? :^)

Answer (score 0):

```
render(
  <div>
    {favouritePersonList[0]}
  </div>
)
```

The code above will try to render an **object** inside the `div` which is wrong.

So, the above code will basically look like this:

```
render(
  <div>
    {
      name: 'Jhon Doe',
      avatarUrl:require('../../social_app/test/profilePic/17.jpg')
    }
  </div>
)
```

You must do something like

```
render(
  <div>
    <Avatar key={favouritePersonList[0]} avatarurl={favouritePersonList[0].avatarUrl} style={styles.favouritePersons} height={40} width={40} activity/>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Nope, `[0]` means here first `Avatar` component. No problem using like this other than that it is not so practical. But, OP wants to render just a one `Avatar` component with the related data.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let favouritePersonList = []
favouritePersonData.foreach((person,index)=>{
        favouritePersonList[index] =  <Avatar key={person} avatarurl={person.avatarUrl} style={styles.favouritePersons} height={40} width={40} activity/>
     })
```

I think this will work for you, but i cant give you a solid reason why your methid didnt work, i would have to build an example and test it a bit

Comment: No, do not suggest `forEach` over `map`.

Comment: Hello, erm it is not working I just tried your solution. @devserkan why it is not good practice to use forEach ? thanks

Comment: @devserkan thats a great explanation

Comment: @SteveBohmbach, I don't know if this is sarcasm but `forEach` does not return anything actually. So, you need to struggle to manipulate the data somehow. Why? `map` is a good tool for those kind of situations. So, yes do not suggest `forEach` over `map`. By the way, I'm not the one downvoted your answer. I'm not an easy downvoter but I understand the people who did this.

Comment: i understand that it doesnt return, i was simply giving him a round about way to create his array. Doing it this way for someone that is newer might make it a bit easier. I did have an error, i was not creating the array the line before the foreach

Comment: I see your point but actually `map` is fine here and it is the right way. On the contrary, suggesting `forEach` to a learner is a bad idea. Because lots of people use `forEach` and ask questions like "I can't see anything in the render". This is why I made my first comment here.